# Show and hide chidren menu items

Tags: reactjs

I Have a mobile menu where I want to show the child items. I created a component that identifies which items have children in the menu.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { BiRightArrow } from 'react-icons/bi'

const OverlayMenuChild = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}>
      <BiRightArrow
        style={{
          verticalAlign: 'bottom',
          marginLeft: '4px'
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default OverlayMenuChild
```

I tested it and all items with children receive this arrow

[image]

So I created a useState to handle items that have children.

If a set the state to true that happens:

```js
 const [childExpand, setChildExpand] = useState(true)

  const handleExpand = () => {
    setChildExpand(prev => !prev)
  }
```

[image]

Children are shown

What I'm trying to do but it doesn't work:

```js
 const [childExpand, setChildExpand] = useState(false)

  const handleExpand = () => {
    setChildExpand(prev => !prev)
  }
```

```js
 <ul className="overlayMenu">
          {
            // father items
            wpMenu.menuItems.nodes.map(item =>
              !item.parentId ? (
                <li key={item.id}>
                  <Link to={item.url} activeClassName="nav-active">
                    {item.label}
                    {
                      // item with child
                      item.childItems.nodes.length !== 0 && (
                        <OverlayMenuChild onClick={handleExpand} />
                      )
                    }
                  </Link>
                  {
                    // children items
                    item.childItems.nodes.length !== 0 && childExpand ? (
                      <ul>
                        {item.childItems.nodes.map(chidItem => (
                          <li key={chidItem.id}>
                            <Link
                              to={chidItem.url}
                              activeClassName="nav-active"
                            >
                              {chidItem.label}
                            </Link>
                          </li>
                        ))}
                      </ul>
                    ) : null
                  }
                </li>
              ) : null
            )
          }
        </ul>
```

I tried to work with the props for the styled components but didn't get any results.

```css
li {
        display: ${props => (props.childExpand ? 'none' : 'block')};
        margin: 0 0 20px 0;
      }
```

I also tried to preventDefaulf () on the link but it also didn't work.

Comment: Here " ! item.parentId ? ". Remove this "!" and than try.

Comment: Only children are displayed.

Comment: ( item.childItems.nodes.length !== 0 && childExpand ?  ) change && to ||. than try. If that also dont work than change above condition to only " childExpand ? ". That should work

Comment: All children are displayed. As if I had set useState to true.